# Match value in another sheet and copy data to current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets. When a value is entered in column 2 of `Sheet2`, I need to find the value in column C of `Sheet1`, then copy another value from the same row where the value matched to a column 3 in `Sheet2`. So far I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        rowNumber = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        If Not rowNumber Is Nothing Then
            Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range(rowNumber, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However, nothing happens when I use this code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong

```
Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

If there is no match you can't get a row number from a Nothing range.

```
rowNumber = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

The row you want to update is probably `Target.row` not `rowNumber` and
`Range(rowNumber,1)` should be `Cells(rowNumber,1)`

```
Cells(rowNumber, 3).Value = Sheet1.Range(rowNumber, 1).Value
```

Try

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub

    Dim wb As Workbook, Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rowNumber As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find( _
        What:=Target.Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rowNumber = rng.Row
        Sheet2.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. The sheet naming mismatch occured after I pasted the code here. I did not want to use original sheet names. I used this code and it fails to find values. I think it's because the column I'm searching in has combined rows. Any solution to overcome this?

Comment: When I say combined , it means for example rows 5,6,7 are combined to just row 5.

Comment: I can confirm it's not working when the rows are combined. If I use a value that is not in a combined row, it's finding the value successfully.

Comment: @Incep Do you means column C on sheet1 has merged cells so C5:C7 is just C5. That should not be a problem. Are any rows in column A merged ? Give me an example of a value it fails to find and the cell range of where it should be found.